# send queue number after logging in

Tags: forms, post, form-submit

in my app, everytime a user logs in, server will determine his/her queue number for the day and send it back to client and client needs to send it with each request. the problem is, how do I do this? where can I embed the queue number in the response (after credential submission, response payload can't be reached anymore). putting the queue number in the redirect seems unsafe even with TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the XHR request for the login. By doing this, login process will be done in background and you don't have to redirect. And once you retrieve the queue number from XHR request, you can use it for further request or redirect.

Comment: well, per company policy, ajax is not permitted for login. it has to be form submission